# input要素のtype=fileで指定するファイルの有無を確認したい

Tags: javascript

Javascriptでinput要素のtype=fileで指定するファイルの有無を確認したいのですが使用しているIEのバージョンが8のためFile APIが使えません。どういったコードを書けば確認できるのでしょうか。fileSizeプロパティを使うなどするのでしょうか。ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 指定したファイルはどう使われるのでしょうか？フォームでどこかへ送信？受け取り側で中身が無いならエラーとするしかないかと思いました。

Comment: 相手のメールアドレスに添付されて送られる形です。経験が浅く分からないことばかりですがたくさん教えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value`プロパティで読み取りができる(値の設定はできないが)はずなので、それでファイル名が設定されたかどうか調べられます。

(ディスク上にファイルが存在するかどうかという場合：ファイル選択時にフォルダに存在しないファイル名を入力したとすると受け入れられないはずなので、ディスク上に存在しないファイルは指定ができないはず）

```js
function check(){
  if(document.File.UPLOADFILE.value)
    alert("既に設定されています");
  else
    alert("設定されていません");
}
```

```html
<form name="File">
<input type="file" name="UPLOADFILE">
</form>
<br />
<button onclick="check()">調べる</button>
```

Comment: ファイルを選択してから、実体を消せば指定は残ったままになりますね。

Comment: 試してませんけど、それって何がしたいんですかね？

Comment: 「ディスク上に存在しないファイルは指定ができないはず」と有ったので、重箱の隅的なツッコミをしてしまいました。すみません。なので、質問の方に付けたコメントに繋がっていくのですが、FileAPIも使えなければ、JavaScript上で何かすることもできないですし、結局サーバ側に送った時点でトラップするしかないよねーと思っています。

Comment: まあそうですよね。。。。。。。

Answer (score 2):

メールアドレス向けに添付で送信されるとのことですので、フォームからデータを受け取ってメールを送信するプログラムの方でファイルの有無をチェックして、エラーとするしかないかと思います。

JavaScriptでフォーム上のエラーチェックをしても、フォームを受け取るプログラムが直接ブラウザで呼び出されることもあるので、JavaScriptでのバリデーションだけで無くプログラム側でもバリデーションが必要です。

他にもセキュリティ的な注意点もあるので、そういう情報についても勉強されるとよいかと思います。